# How can pytest send emails to the test case submitter

Tags: pytest

I have used pytest to run the python test cases automatically, but how can I use pytest to send the case result report to a certain mailbox? 
Is there any sending email related plugins in pytest?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this is the job of the continuous integration server rather then the test tool.  A common setup is to run `pytest --junitxml=results.xml` on the CI server which can then parse the test result, usually they can also combine this with the VCS (hg, git, ...) information to figure out who committed the changes and email just those people.  E.g. Jenkins supports all of this.